# Android: Copy individual directory from assets to SD Card

Tags: android, assets, android-sdcard

i want copy just specific folder from assets. 
can you help me??? I just find how to copy all file or directory from assets

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to copy files in 'assets' to sdcard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have subdirectories within assets.

Comment: Sure you can. You can have `assets/book/contents.json`, for example.